# Few is/are self disciplined enough to study everyday for the CAT?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

> Few is/are self disciplined enough to study everyday for the CAT.

My approach:

Few means at least more than one, so I used a plural verb.

Is my approach right according to subject verb agreement rules? Please correct me if i am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"few" is connected with a plural noun.

- Few people attended the religious service.

It can be used without noun:

- Many are called, but few are chosen. Bible.